# Testng beanshell group intersection

Tags: testng, beanshell

I am using testng(version 7.3.0) suites defined with beanshell like the one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="SuiteTest" parallel="classes" thread-count="4">
    <method-selectors>
        <method-selector>
            <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[ return groups.containsKey(groups.containsKey("test1")) && groups.containsKey("test2") && !groups.containsKey("test3")]]>
            </script>
        </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>
    <test name="regression pack">
        <packages>
            <package name="test.dev.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I run tests by executing `mvn clean test -DtestSuite={theSuiteName}` where **testSuite** is a placeholder defined in maven-surefire-plugin suiteXmlFile configuration:

```
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
   <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
         <suiteXmlFile>/src/test/resources/suites/${testSuite}</suiteXmlFile>
....
```

Recently I needed to use testng-failed.xml suite and there is something I don't understand. If 3 tests fail from a class, the whole class is rerun at testng-failed suite - even those that passed in the first place. After some investigation I am sure that the beanshell is the reason here. Does anybody knows why and maybe a possible solution? Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add the TestNG version information as well along with how you are running your tests. The latest released version of TestNG is `7.4.0`

Comment: 've managed to solve my problem by updating the testng-failed.xml removing the beanshell section( <method-selectors> object) but couldn't find any reason why does not work with beanshell inside